# 95% CI for survival linear combination (interaction) using vcov

Tags: r, linear-algebra, survival-analysis, interaction, survival

i have this model

[image]

Where TD is a binary variable, and Strata is a numeric variable equals to {1,2,3}. I need to get 95% CI for this two linear combinations:

[image]

I have this function to construct confidence intervals

```
pwp_gt_int <- coxph(Surv(tstart2,tstop2,status==1) ~ TD+ TD:strata(event)
mod_summ <- summary(pwp_gt_int)
coefs <- modsum$coefficients
X <- model.matrix(pwp_gt_int)
dof <- nrow(X) - ncol(X)
coefs_var <- vcov(pwp_gt_int)
halfCI <- qt(0.975, dof) * sqrt(diag(coefs_var))

matrix(c(coefs - halfCI, coefs + halfCI), nrow=3)
```

but i need something like this

```
    coefs[2] = coefs[1] + 2*coefs[2]
    coefs[3] = coefs[1] + 3*coefs[3]
matrix(c(coefs - halfCI, coefs + halfCI), nrow=3)
```

But the CI's i got are not plausible, i'm think im not getting right the variance-covariance matrix for the linear combinations.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're asking for two different things - one is the variance of a linear combination and the other is a confidence interval (and as such, a variance) for a non-linear combination.  The linear combination is relatively easy.  We know that the variance of a linear combination is:

[image]

where A is a matrix of constants and V(b) is the variance-covariance matrix of the random variables (in this case, the coefficients).  If your coefficient vector has three values in it, and you want to do as you suggest in your last block of code, then the you would define:

[image]

or in R as:

```
A = matrix(c(1,1,2,0,0,3), ncol=3)
```

Then, you could make the linear combinations and their variances with:

```
b <- matrix(coef(pwp_gt_int)[1:3], ncol=1)
V <- vcov(pwp_gt_int)[1:3,1:3]
lincom <- A %*% b
v_lincom <- A %*% V %*% t(A)
sds <- sqrt(diag(v_lincom))
crit <- qt(.975, dof)
cis <- cbind(lincom - crit*sds, sincom + crit*sds)
```

That would be the confidence interval for the linear combination.  The problem is that there isn't such an easy formula for the variance of a non-linear combination.  Further, the confidence intervals may be asymmetric.  One thing you could do is an end-point transformation, where you take `lincom` and `cis` and then exponentiate all of them.  Another option would be a parametric bootstrap.  Here's what that would look like.

```
B <- MASS::mvrnorm(2500, b, V)
nlcom <- exp(A %*% b)
nlsim <- exp(A %*% t(B))
nlcis <- apply(nlsim, 1, quantile, c(.025,.975))
```

Now, `nlcis` would have the confidence bounds for the non-linear combination.  This should work given your data, but without the data to try it out, I'm not sure.

Comment: This worked oerfectly, you are amazing. Thank you very much.